# In a directed graph, will the shortest path s-t always contain the minimum edge of the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

For the following question:

> Consider a directed graph with distinct and nonnegative edge lengths and a source vertex s.  Fix a destination vertex t, and assume that the graph contains at least one s-t path.  Which of the following statements are true?
>
> - The shortest s-t path must exclude the maximum-length edge of G.
> - There is a shortest s-t path with no repeated vertices (i.e., a "simple" or "loopless" such path).
> - The shortest (i.e., minimum-length) s-t path might have as many as n – 1 edges, where n is the number of vertices.
> - **The shortest s-t path must include the minimum-length edge of G.**

I had checked the last option, but got this feedback:

> The statement *"The shortest s-t path must include the minimum-length edge of G."* is incorrect.

Could anyone help me to picture a counterexample of this? Is it because if there is a loop, the length edge of G won't be the length from its source to its destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edges that are on the shortest path between s and t do not need to include the shortest nor the longest edge of the graph. A trivial example is where s and t are the ends of the same edge, and that is the only path between s and t: that means there really isn't a choice... it is *that* edge, and no other edge, irrespective of the lengths of any of the edges in the graph.

It has nothing to do with loops.

Here is another example:

[image]

Also here there is one path between s and t, and it is clear there are many edges in the graph that have a lesser length than the two edges that are on the path between s and t.

Comment: Thanks, I have misunderstood the question, I thought the minimum-lenth edgei sth like the length of the graph, now I realize it means the shortest edge of all the M edges.

Comment: I guessed there had to be some misunderstanding here. Wasn't sure whether it was the concept of path, of spanning tree, or anything like that. Glad it got sorted out.